# How to get login/password/regiser data saved into excel sheet?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, authentication

So far in Unity I have made GUI for the login and register where I get the input field text data to check on and transfer to next scene. I want to be able to login with a database which is to be saved in excel on my site server. I am ok with C# and I am new to this and I do not know how do I pursue this. Please refer example so I can understand it fully and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not use Excel as your database. Create a real database using SQL on your server. Then it's trivial to connect and verify a user using c#. You can find plenty of resources online to achieve this. I recommend [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program) tutorial.

Now if you (for some strange reason) MUST use excel to store user info. You would have to write some sort of server side script that can handle POST and GET queries in order to read/write to the excel file. PhP would be a suitable language for this. But I do not recommend doing this at all.